# Removing only single blank space from a cell

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am using regex to identify single space between words and replace them with underscore. 
1. For example Say F1 has value "company name    Name of Institution".
2. Notice single space between company name and Name of institution.
3. However the two fields are separated by multiple space

Using the below code to solve for this issue.

```
Sub matchfile2()
Const marker As String = "_"
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rx, s As String, t As String, parts
Set rx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
lrow = Cells(Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
For A_row = 1 To lrow ' Last row t o consider
    s = Range("F" & A_row)
'     Set s = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        rx.Pattern = "(\w)+ (?=\w)" 
        rx.Global = True ' find all, not only the first match

        t = rx.Replace(s, "$1_")

Next A_row
End Sub
```

However, this results in Value as "y_name    e_f_Institution" takes 1 character before the space. 
How do we change the code to result in "company_name  Name_of_institution"

Comment: Can you provide some better examples?  It seems to me like this is going to be near on impossible to solve programmatically without some AI thrown in.  Surely the name of the company and the name of the institution don't all follow a nice neat format as you've outlined?  What if you have "Company Name_of_Institution" or "Company_Name_Extended Institution" ... just all sounds too hard if that's the case.

Comment: @Skin . Basically the cell has two words in it "Company Name(more than two spaces" Name of institution". I am able to separate the two words using regx {2, }. so now, Let's say I am replacing "more than two spaces " to #, I have "Company Name# Name of Institution". Now i Was looking if i can replace the blanks with "_". RX pattern "(\w)+ (?=\w)"  does identify the cases, but I need the syntax/option to use in replace. "$1_" keeps only the last letter, so i get "y_name" & "e_f_Institution".

Comment: ok, so you’re saying there are always 2 or more spaces between company name and name of institution?

Comment: Yes, Which can be tackled by the other regx i used.  Need syntax to retain the whole word in rx.Replace(s, "$1_"). New to regx

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you use `(\w)+`.
I am not sure about the details, but `$1` only maintains the last capture for this group (the last letter).
Try to simply use `(\w+)`. This puts the full word in this capturing group and makes it reappear at `$1`.

Comment: Worked like charm.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HarshVardhan in that case you can accept the answer by clicking the check button just below the downvote button :) that way you'll let other users know you have found your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you were happy to steer clear of Regex then this method should work for you.

```
Public Sub RetrieveText()
    Dim strText As String, strCompany As String, strInstitution As String

    strText = "Company Name  Name of Institution"

    strCompany = Split(strText, "  ")(0)
    strInstitution = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(strText), "  ")(0))

    Debug.Print strCompany
    Debug.Print strInstitution

    ' ... or this ...
    strCompany = Trim(Mid(strText, 1, InStr(1, strText, "  ")))
    strInstitution = Trim(Mid(strText, InStr(1, strText, "  ")))

    Debug.Print strCompany
    Debug.Print strInstitution
End Sub
```

... it's another option and kind of simplifies it, at least, it does for me.  :-)  Regex is incredibly powerful but hard for a lot of people to understand and depending on the support of your solution, may be a consideration.

Anyway, up to you!

Comment: I tried this, but this will break the word by spaces, I will have to do another set of operation to join the words, which by loss of "Multiple spaces" now will be tougher to identify. But let me beat some more time around it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  That code splits by 2 spaces, so you get the 2 values out, it doesn't break up every word in the string.  Try it and you'll see.  Clearly I'm not understanding your requirement in its entirety.  All good anyway.

Comment: Oh, you then want to put it back together.  I'd just use a replace statement.  You'll have less code your way but I don't always go for less code.  Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
    rx.Pattern = "(\w+) (?=\w)" ' match two or more spaces
    rx.Global = True ' find all, not only the first match
    t = rx.Replace(s, "$1_")
```

Answering, for anyone else looking for similar situation.